# Which variables are different between two different datasets?

Tags: r, variables, difference

So I have two different datasets(df_test and df_test_2), and I want to be able to tell the difference between them. I know I can use the setdiff to tell the differences between them but I need to know where they are different. For example, I want to look at the rows where var_1 is different and everything else is the same, and I also want to do the same analysis with var_2 and all the other variables. Is there anyway I can have flags for these variables?

```
df_test <- data.frame(id = c(0,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5)
                          , var_1 = c("h","a","b","b","c","d","e","f","m"),
                          var_2=c("companyf","companyA","companyB","companyc","companyD","companyf","companyg","companyh","companyi"),
                          var_3=c(100,10,10,11,20,30,40,50,5))

    df_test_2= data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
                             , var_1 = c("a","b","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),
                             var_2=c("companyA","companyBB","companyc","companyD","companyf","companyg","companyh","companyi","companyii","companyff"),
                             var_3=c(10,10,11,200,30,40,50,5,40,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try to modify your approach using `setdiff` and `which`

> To search for var_1 values that exist in df1 but not in df2

```
df1[which(df1$var_1 == setdiff(df1$var_1,df2$var_1)),]
```

> Output for var_1

```
  id var_1    var_2 var_3
9  5     m companyi     5
```

> To search for var_2 values that exist in df1 but not in df2

```
df1[which(df1$var_2 == setdiff(df1$var_2,df2$var_2)),]
```

> Output for var_2

```
id var_1    var_2 var_3
3  1     b companyB    10
```

Comment: is there a way to do this systematically? to add a flag to the the rows?